# How to get value of ng-Model into Controller angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me to check this part of code.

```
<body ng-app = "myApp">
<h1>FORM </h1>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
    <p><label>Username : </label><input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username" id="username" /></p>
    <p><label>Email : </label><input type="email" ng-model="user.email"/></p>
    <p><label>Verifikasi Email : </label><input type="email" ng-model="user.verify_email"  /></p>
    <p><label>Password : </label><input type="password"  ng-model="user.password" id="password" /></p>
    <button type="button" ng-click = "add()"  >Sig In</button>
</div>
</body>
```

In my Javascript:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.user = {};
$scope.add = function(){
     $scope.data = [
                    { nama : $scope.user.username},
                    { email : $scope.user.email},
                    {password : $scope.user.password } ];
console.log($scope.data);
    }               
 });
```

Thanks for you all. I already update my script. When I click the button, the console didn't print the data. Why? I think there is something wrong.

Comment: Try to define the user object before referencing it, like `$scope.user = {} ; $scope.data = ...`

Comment: Thats because you have written `user.username`, but `$scope.user` is not defined.

Comment: I think you should read about angular tutorials and ap docs .Please Check out https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Thanks. I try like what you said. I already update it. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't define `user`

But that shouldn't be the problem if you use only `user` as model like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user" name="username" id="username" />
```

It'll be added as property in the `scope` without any worries.

But you have added property `username` in `user`.

As `user` is `undefined` so the scenario will be `undefined.username` which is not permitted.

Try to defined `user` as object then any property will automically added.

Like this

```
$scope.user={};
```

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML you should

```
<body ng-app = "myApp"> 

    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p><label>Username : </label><input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username" id="username" /></p>
        <p><label>Email : </label><input type="email" ng-model="user.email"/></p>
        <p><label>Verifikasi Email : </label><input type="email" ng-model="user.verify_email"  /></p>
        <p><label>Password : </label><input type="password"  ng-model="user.password" id="password" /></p>
        <button type="button" ng-click = "add(user)"  >Sig In</button> 
    </div> 

</body>
```

in case of

> ***ng-click = "add()"***

use

> ***ng-click = "add(user)"***

in your controller

```
$scope.add = function(user){

    $scope.data = [
        { name : user.username},
        { email : user.email},
        {password : user.password } 
    ];

    console.log($scope.data);

}); // End add Function
```